# How to get the row number to copy a row from one spreadsheet to another in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recorded a Macro in Google Sheets to copy data from on sheet to the next but when I run it, it only overwrites the data in the target sheet. I have searched how to make it copy to the next new line but had no luck.

This is my recorded Script:

```
function movetonext() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet5'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:C3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet4!A2:C2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet4'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
}
```

Comment: Sheet.getLastRow();

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Copy the values into the active range on target sheet or append them at the bottom of the already existing data?